# Strapi V4: script entry point in package.json?

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to deploy Strapi on fly.io.
It says that

> Your Node app doesn't define a start script in package.json.  You will
> need to add one before you deploy.  Also be sure to set your listen
> port to 8080 using code similar to the following:
>
> ```
> const port = process.env.PORT || "8080";
> ```
>
> If you need custom packages installed, or have problems with your
> deployment build, you may need to edit the Dockerfile for app-specific
> changes. If you need help, please post on https://community.fly.io.

What should I do ?
Thanks !